# How to properly punctuate dialogue?

Tags: punctuation

Consider the following statement;

> He commented that,"I have such a miserable cold, your sarcastic
>   remarks are hardly making any effect on me."

How to know the usage of 'that' here? Is 'that' redundant here?

Also about punctuation;

> "I have such a miserable cold, your sarcastic remarks are hardly
>   making any effect on me," He commented.

Should there be comma or full-stop at '...effect on me," He commented.

Also in following, should there be comma or full stop after '**He commented**';

> **He commented."I have** such a miserable cold, your sarcastic remarks are 
>   hardly making any effect on me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) "That" is more than redundant; it is incorrect. We would use it before unquoted reported speech - he commented that he had such a cold that [someone's] sarcastic remarks were hardly making any effect on him. You original sentence would be acceptable without 'that'.

(2) You asked:

> Also about punctuation;
>
> "I have such a miserable cold, your sarcastic remarks are hardly
>   making any effect on me," He commented.
>
> Should there be comma or full-stop at '...effect on me," He commented.

Do not capitalise "he"; it does not start a new sentence . There should be a comma after "me".

(3) There can be a comma (it is optional).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Sorry for the mistake, I edited out the 'He commented' in the third question.